# Captaincasa grid paging

Tags: java, user-interface, frameworks

I'm looking to implement any paging functionality on top of the grid component like google search paging, where at the bottom there is an option to navigate user from first to last page of the search result, do we have any existing example?

Currently found out load on demand demo, but it required extra effort when user sort or filter data  [demo](https://www.captaincasademo.com/ccdemos/workplace.workplaceRisc.risc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you are looking for a paging/scrolling using buttons (in addition to the normal scrollbar scrolling) to scroll through grid lines.

The FIXGRID has some server-side API which allows access/update to the scrolling:

```
FIXGRIDBinding.getSbvalue() ==> current scroll position
FIXGRIDBinding.getSbvisibleamount() ==> number of lines currently displayed
FIXGRIDBinding.getSbmax() ==> max scroll position
FIXGRIDBinding.setSbvalue() ==> set/update scroll position
```

So you can build your paging (e.g. dynamic arrangement of buttons/links/...) using this API.

PS: We take your idea and may add some addon-page-bean-component doing this. But: you can easily implement on your own - do not wait for us! ;-)

Comment: We added a corresponding page-bean-component into the addons-package. Demo workplace => Addons => Page Bean Components => Grid paging. Up to date version of demo workplace: http://captaincasademo.com/ccdemos/workplace.workplaceRisc.risc

Source code is available in eclnt_pbc.zip of version 20210615.